# I got "The transformer you selected is invalid" error when creating a Facebook Creative via Business API

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

I'm creating Facebook Dynamic Ads for vehicle vertical for multiple dealerships. The 95% of the times the call to create a creative for a dynamic ad works well, however when the url contains *VehicleSearchResults* in the URL it fails.

This is the call error example using the Python SDK:

Path: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/act_xxxxxxxxx/adcreatives

```
Params: {
'name': '{{vehicle.price}} - {{vehicle.title}}._CREATIVE',
'product_set_id': u'1234567890',
'url_tags': '',
'object_story_spec': '{
    "page_id":"1234567890",
    "template_data":{
        "call_to_action":{
            "type":"SHOP_NOW",
            "value":{
                "link":"https://www.mywebpage.com/VehicleSearchResults?search=preowned&model={{vehicle.model | urlencode}}"}},
                "description":"","link":"https://www.mywebpage.com/VehicleSearchResults?search=preowned&model={{vehicle.model | urlencode}}",
                "message":"","name":"{{vehicle.price}} - {{vehicle.title}}"}}',
'template_url_spec': '{
    "web":{
        "url":"https://www.mywebpage.com/VehicleSearchResults?search=preowned&model={{vehicle.model | urlencode}}"}}',
'applink_treatment': 'web_only'
```

}

Response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 100,
        "is_transient": false,
        "error_subcode": 1487893,
        "error_user_msg": "The transformer you selected is invalid.",
        "error_user_title": "The template field transformer is invalid",
        "message": "Invalid parameter",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "fbtrace_id": "ABhi8rjLjor"
    }
}
```

I followed the guide described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/dynamic-ads-auto/ads-management) and is in this page where **urlencode** transformer is mentioned and it works well as long as the text *VehicleSearchResults* is not present in the URL. When I remove it from the URL the call works well, but I did not find any documentation related to the url transformers and/or use cases and exceptions.